# Linux "iostat" to .csv file using Perl

Tags: linux, perl, iostat

I am experimenting with the `iostat -c 1` command, and I was wondering if there is a simple way of reading the current output and then separating the values so that I could generate a `.csv` file.

The goal is to be able to generate graphs, using the data outputted by `iostat` over a time period. I'm not looking for a complete script, just some hints that would help me achieve my goal.

Comment: why not use a full fledged monitoring tool like check_mk /nagios ?

Comment: Failing that, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'd start with munin or grafana rather than trying to roll my own, but good luck either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically the same data that `iostat` collects and displays is also collected by sysstat a.k.a. `sar`

[`sar`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sar) comes with a supporting tool [`sadf`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sadf) that can easily display the collected stats in a number of convenient formats, including , XML, JSON and CSV.

I.e. for CSV try something like:

```
sadf -dh -- <sar options>
```

Where for instance the sar options `-b -d` will display block device IO.

```
sadf -dh -- -b -d
```

This cheat sheet might point you at other useful sar options:

[image: http://www.brendangregg.com/Perf/linux_observability_sar.png]
<sub>(source: [brendangregg.com](http://www.brendangregg.com/Perf/linux_observability_sar.png))</sub>